# sql INNER JOIN table variable ON VS. INNER JOIN (select) ON

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-performance

I'm wondering if using a table variable is more or less performant than using an inner join (select)
Example:

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE(Id int)  
INSERT INTO @tab  
SELECT Id  
FROM SomeTable  
WHERE SomeDate = "10 DAYS AGO" 

SELECT *
FROM SomeOtherTable
INNER JOIN @tab t
ON SomeOtherTable.id = t.id  

--VERSUS--

SELECT *  
FROM SomeOtherTable  
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeDate = "10 DAYS AGO") t  
ON SomeOtherTable.id = t.id
```

For large queries the first is more maintainable if you have to make the same join a few times, but what is the most performant?

Greetings

Comment: What about `SELECT * FROM SomeOtherTable WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeDate = "10 DAYS AGO")`, indexing for `SomeDate` and including `Id`?

Comment: check with mysql **explain**, if I am not wrong in general you want a trick to make the inner (selct from) executed first, kind of from inside out execution. Also google for sql query optimization or sql join optimization

Comment: I've assumed SQL Server, please let me know if that is correct.

Comment: @MartinSmith: quite correct, sorry for not mentioning.
everyone: I do not have the rights to create indexes, nor are there any defined ATM.(Using SCSM DWDataMart for those who know it).
Using a #temp table has been unadvised by a professional that I walk into from time to time.

Comment: @user972706 - You'd need to test for your specific case. Also can you explain a bit more about "make the same join a few times" I had in mind a situation with multiple statements. If it is a single statement please post the type of query and also check does the plan actually show it being evaluated multiple times.

Comment: if you have UNION's to do.
In my case I have to do the same query with a few different date-ranges, and they HAVE to be returned in one table, because they are used in SSRS.

Comment: @user972706 - Ah right in that case I can see that it **would** end up evaluating that part multiple times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL Server does not maintain detailed statistics for table variables or automatically recompile to reflect less granular cardinality information changes (without TF 2453) so will generally assume that they output a single row.

This means that sometimes you will get a sub optimal join strategy. The second version can use statistics and also avoids the overhead of inserting the intermediate results into a temporary object.

However if the second query is expensive to evaluate as `SomeDate` is not indexed you may get improved performance from materialising this up front (compared to repeatedly re-evaluating).

You could also consider using a `#temp` table as this avoids the statistics issue. [Some people suggest **never** using a table variable in JOINs](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/79411/are-table-variables-a-bad-thing)